# Cocoa + CoreAnimation: Animated List of Custom Subviews

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, core-animation, nscollectionview

I've been trying to get this right for weeks now, and though I've learned a lot through my misfires, at this point, I just need a solution. The issue is with unpacking the seemingly overlapping graphics and UI APIs included in Cocoa, many of which produce similar effects, but feature unique limitations that I've often discovered only after investing many hours into an implementation.

I'm new to Cocoa, but not to programming, and I'm trying to create a Mac app with a very customized UI – think Capo, Garageband, or Billings. One view in my window will display an ordered list of subviews, each of which does a lot of custom drawing, and each must support a "selected" state and drag-reordering. The subviews do not need to support being dragged outside of their superview.

Ideally, a drag will give animated feedback as it happens, pushing neighboring sibling views to make space, e.g. toolbar icons or the Safari bookmarks bar.  The trouble is, I can't seem to land on the right pack of technologies to get this right. I've done the subviews as NSView subclasses in an NSCollectionView and also as CALayers in a custom CollectionView-like NSView, and neither seems to offer the perfect solution. That said, the first option seems the better of the two for its superior handling of mouse events.

I've not yet tried doing this as a TableView, and I don't want to go down that path without some indication I'm on the right track. Extensive Googling has shown only that there aren't any up-to-date resources on CoreAnimation-enabled reordering or dragging. As such a standard feature of the OS X UI, I feel like this should be easier!

Any help from anyone on what the right tools are for this job would be greatly appreciated. TIA.